# How to get data in navbar layout from controller using innertia:render()

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-10

I want to send data from controller and get everywhere in my project like navbar,sidebar,footer,title etc,,im using innertia with laravel and vue3.

**Im trying to this,**
return Innertia:render('Dashboard')->withShareData(['data',$data]);

I want to get data from controller to show in navbar item.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.